# Local Heroku/Ruby/Facebook development problems

Tags: ruby, facebook, heroku, sinatra, koala

UPDATE: See solution at the bottom.

I'm new to Ruby and Heroku development. I deployed an app on Facebook with Heroku/Ruby hosting. The default Ruby/FB app that Heroku deploys runs fine when running on Heroku. However, when I cloned my heroku app to run locally I started running into problems.

The first problem was fixed by adding `require "rubygems"` to the top off my app.rb, and then solved Facebook iFrame problems by adding `set :protection, :except => :frame_options` to app.rb.

Now my problem is that @app is nil after these lines run when there is no access_token yet.

```
@graph  = Koala::Facebook::API.new(session[:access_token])

# Get public details of current application
@app  =  @graph.get_object(ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"])
```

This causes template rendering to break with this error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass:
/Users/todd-chapman/Documents/vivid-winter-3317/views/index.erb:7:in `evaluate_source'
```

What am I doing wrong? Have I missed a step in setting up my local development?

Additional info: This might be related to having sandbox mode enabled in my Facebook app so that I can do local development without SSL.

Thanks!

SOLUTION:

I don't have enough of a rep to answer my own question within 8 hours of asking it, so here's the solution I found.

Since my Facebook app is in sandbox mode to support non-SSL development, the call to `@graph.get_object(ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"])` won't work because sandbox mode apps are only accessible by the Facebook app admins. Thus a nil result is returned.

The long term fix is to set up an SSL reverse proxy so I can develop locally while my Facebook app has sandbox mode turned off.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

Since my Facebook app is in sandbox mode to support non-SSL development, the call to @graph.get_object(ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"]) won't work because sandbox mode apps are only accessible by the Facebook app admins. Thus a nil result is returned.

The long term fix is to set up an SSL reverse proxy so I can develop locally while my Facebook app has sandbox mode turned off. There's a good article on that here: http://www.subelsky.com/2012/01/my-twelve-factor-app-development.html

Comment: Surely then the solution is to become an admin in Facebook for the app you are developing.